Gradients in "On the difficulty of training Recurrent Neural Networks"
In the paper we have
$$
x_t=F(x_{t-1},u_t,\theta) \\
x_t=W_{rec}\sigma(x_{t-1})+W_{in}u_t+b
$$
and then some error function $\varepsilon$, and we are interesting in taking the derivative w.R.t $\theta$
At a single timestamp $t$ this evaluates to
$$
\frac{\partial\varepsilon_t}{\partial\theta}=\sum(\frac{\partial\varepsilon_t}{\partial x_t}*\frac{\partial x_t}{\partial x_k}*\frac{\partial^{+}x_k}{\partial\theta})
$$
I was wondering about $\frac{\partial^{+}x_k}{\partial\theta}$. They specify that this

refers to the “immediate” partial derivative of
the state xk with respect to θ

Could someone clarify with an example what exactly this means?

The superscript $+$ in the numerator is used to indicate an immediate partial derivative. The latter is defined as a derivative where we differentiate the step-k hidden state with respect to the vectorized hidden-to-hidden weight. The immediate partial derivative is a partial derivative where we regard $h_{[k−1]}$ as constant with respect to $\theta$. For instance if $h_{[k]}$ is the result of applying $k$ time the recursive equation $h_{[k]}=f(h_{[k-1]},\theta)$, the immediate partial derivative of $h_{[k]}$ with respect to $\theta$ is the derivative of $h_{[k]}$ with respect to $\theta$ assuming $h_{[k-1]}$ is constant with respect to $\theta$.
As far as I know this definition was introduced by the author of the paper you cited.

you just repeated what I wrote, I've asked for an clarification example. And the link is not working.

I hope what I wrote can help. When I wrote the answer the link was working. Sorry for that.
